# ADB won't start, can't find any valid solutions - genymotion

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

I'm on debian buster. 
I have genymotion installed and running, and a CRNA app that I'm trying to run. I have Android SDK installed, and set properly in my path. 
I have changed the genymotion settings to point to my Android SDK folder.

When I do `yarn run android` I see

```
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

When I do `adb start-server` I see

```
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

I have run `adb kill-server`, and manually killed and restarted the ADB process many times. Every fix I've found to this issue does not work.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there some comprehensive guide on setting all of this up? I'm willing to do a fresh install if I have to.

Comment: This seems like two `adb` versions are installed on your PC and probably the root of your problem. Can you try to find the location of the outdated `adb` using something similar to `which adb` in the command line and ensure that it's binary location is within the location of the installed Android SDK?

Comment: there is only one result, but it is located in /usr/bin/adb

Comment: @ahasbini I pointed genymotion to that location instead of my sdk folder and it worked!!! Thanks a million

Comment: @Alex P. can you read? Clearly not a dupe, I found that question and it did not have any suitable answers for my issue. My issue was resolved and is distinctly separate from the issue in that question. You are hampering the efforts of people with separate problems with your militant flagging and blatant disregard for post content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad that I was able to help you. :)

As suspected, the machine contains two different versions of `adb` installed, one by the Android SDK, and another installed probably with another tool or program which contains `adb` packaged with it (maybe the fastboot tools). With two versions being executed at different times, the adb server would complain with errors as posted in your question.

Although you were able to solve this by setting genymotion to use the installed tool's `adb`, it is advised to actually uninstall the tool and configure the environment variables (`PATH` and `ANDROID_HOME`) to include the `adb` that came with the Android SDK. This modification would be needed if you would be considering to use more tools that depend on `adb`such as Android Studio or others.